# How do I Change an MVC Actions' Associated View After using 'Add View...' Dialog Previously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

If I use 'Add View' on a new Controller Action in Microsoft MVC, it will create a new view and I don't have to explicitly reference this view when calling it from the Controller:

```
return View();
```

However, what if at some time later I want to point my action to a different View?  Since my Action is already implicitly bound to View created through the 'Add View' dialog, the only way I've found to override this implicit relationship is to explicitly identify the new view when returning from the Action:

```
return View("NewView");
```

Is there any way re-relate the "NewView" View to the Controller Action in the same way that the first View was implicitly bound through the 'Add View' dialog?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the implicit

```
return View();
```

to work out of the box with a different named view you would have to change the name of your controller action.

If you are concerned with "magic strings" and would like to have a little better feeling that the view actually exists I suggest taking a look at [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) which will automatically generate strongly typed constants for your views.